# Edit a file using BASH to change unknown values

Tags: bash, edit

I'm trying to figure out how to change certain parts of a file using simple BASH

Basically I want to go from this

Before:

```
parameter0.1=value
parameter0.2=value
parameter0.3=https://changeme/donotchangeme
parameter0.4=ABCD

parameter1.1=value
parameter1.2=value
parameter1.3=https://changeme/donotchangeme
parameter1.4=WXYZ
```

To this

After:

```
parameter0.1=value
parameter0.2=value
parameter0.3=https://changed/donotchangeme
parameter0.4=QWERTY

parameter1.1=value
parameter1.2=value
parameter1.3=https://changed/donotchangeme
parameter1.4=QWERTY
```

However, I will not know what the value of "changeme", "ABCD" or "WXYZ" actual is. So I can't do a find and replace.

Any ideas?

Comment: is there any criteria for the values you have to change?

Comment: @Tamar
One value is always going to be a URL and the other value is always going to be an SSL certificate thumbprint. I won't know the original values (i.e. they could be anything) but I will know what I want the values to become.

Comment: is it always the '1.4' parameter? and is it based on '1.3' parameter?

Comment: @Tamar Yes I the two lines I want to change will always be parameter1.3 and parameter1.4 but they aren't always going to be necessarily be related to each - i.e. the SSL thumbprint may not correspond with the https URL

Comment: just for clarificaton, do you want to change the value that comes after `parameterx.4=' to a fixed value, say `QWERTY` for all groups of four parameters?

Comment: @ThomasKühn Yes that is correct. And for `paramterX.3` I want to change whatever is after `https://` and before `/donotchangeme` to a fixed value. i.e. In the example above, also change `changeme` to `changed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that your given input is stored in `input.txt`, then the following `sed` command should do what you desire.

```
cat input.txt | sed -e '/parameter.\.3=/s_=https://[^/]*_=https://changed_' -e '/parameter.\.4=/s_=.*$_=QWERTY_'
```

In short, instead of searching for the text that you want to replace (which you don't know), search for the text that surrounds said text and replace accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.
The parameterX.3 is getting the `https://` portion stripped out
`parameter0.3changed/donotchangeme`

Comment: hardcoding `=https://` into the command can fix that

`cat spec_orig | sed -e '/parameter.\.3=/s_=https://[^/]*_=https://changed_' -e '/parameter.\.4=/s_=.*$_=QWERTY_'`

Comment: Thanks :) Appreciate the help